# Difficulty in adding constraint to imageview in xcode 10.but unable to add constraint zero to the entire imageView

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

Trying to set top zero, lead zero ,trail zero but it is not accepting the zero value rather it is showing "standard" string in the place where I need to add constraints.

example of error where I need to apply constraint:
[image: example of error where I need to apply constraint]

Answer (score 0):

The word "Standard" is just a placeholder. Please go ahead and type 0 into it, uncheck the "Constraint to margins" checkbox and hit Add Constraint button.

Comment: Actually I tried but after adding zero to top constraint and when I add constraint to right side then automatic the top constraint erases and shows up "standard" key.